# Where is compiler in exe programs?

Tags: exe

I know that for some code to work on computer, it should be compiled or interpreted, but some programs such as games or other desktop applications are run when clicked on. I wonder where the compiler or interpreter is. Is it embedded inside the program or there is something extremely advanced to understand?

Comment: It’s on the person’s machine who compiles the exe

Comment: A compiler is like a factory robot: it's only needed to create the executable code, but once the product is built you don't need it anymore to use the product.

Comment: Whereas an interpreter is indeed more like a CD player - you as the consumer do need it to use the CD.

Comment: thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

exe programs like games are already the result of compiling. When you click on a exe, no compiler is necessary anymore. The compiler is on the computer of the developer.

Interpreted languages like Python or JavaScript need an engine to run on your computer. That is not the same as a compiler.